# C# make desire Json format

Tags: javascript, c#, json

I want to have Json object like this:

In have this code in C#:

```
var list = new ArrayList();
foreach (var item in stats)
{
    list.Add(new { item.date.Date, item.conversions });
}

return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { list });
```

Now my Json is something Like this:

[image]

I want to have a Json in this format:

```
//{01/21/2017,14}
//{01/22/2017,17}
//{01/23/2017,50}
//{01/24/2017,0}
//{01/25/2017,2}
//{01/26/2017,0}
```

Comment: `{ something, something}` is not a valid JSON format. JSON is  a `{key: value}` pair. Try using arrays instead: `["01/21/2017", "14"]`

Comment: what means the "14,17,50,0,2,0" values after each date?

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio It's amount of something in each day

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestsJson
{
    class Model
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        public int Clicks { get; set; }

        public Model(DateTime date, int clicks)
        {
            Date = date;
            Clicks = clicks;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var data = new List<Model>()
            {
                new Model(new DateTime(2017, 01, 21), 14),
                new Model(new DateTime(2017, 01, 22), 17),
                new Model(new DateTime(2017, 01, 23), 50),
                new Model(new DateTime(2017, 01, 24), 0),
                new Model(new DateTime(2017, 01, 25), 2),
                new Model(new DateTime(2017, 01, 26), 0)
            };

            foreach (var model in data)
            {
                var json = "{" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model.Date.ToShortDateString()) + ":" + model.Clicks + "}";
                Console.WriteLine(json);
            }

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's pretty self explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating strings as your JSON objects. For example:

```
var list = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in stats)
     {
         list.Add(String.Format("{0},{1}",item.date.Date, item.conversions));
     }

return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { list });

//I haven't tested the code.
```